# Remove 'page' option from will_paginate URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm using rails and will_paginate gem. Is it possible to remove 'page' option from URL to other place - e.g. params (without ajax) ?

```
For example instead www.site.com/products?page=2, always show www.site.com/products
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. You want to remove this option from pagination links? Why?

Comment: Once you have removed it, how do you know what page to show?

Comment: I mean that option should be inside params, but not in the url path. It works with ajax, but I don't need ajax in this case. Just wanna to know if it possible

Comment: What have you tried? We expect to see some sample code showing you've given this some effort instead of just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, since you are doing a using an HTTP GET method, so you need to pass the parameters to allow the controller function to search the objects.
The parameters hash goes on POST methods.

If you want an alternative solution, you can look at [datatables](https://datatables.net/) for tables and pagination, which is done purely in javascript, but you need to fetch all the results first.